# Add to rename tracking in mercurial after commit

Tags: mercurial, rename, tortoisehg

Simple scenario:

I have renamed a file. The changes are committed and pushed. I didn't have used `hg rename`.

How can I tell mercurial that an add/remove in a commit was a rename? Is there something like the svn .mergeinfo that I can edit manually?

(It is not the last commit, so solution with amending to a commit are nice, but won't help me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. `hg update` to the commit before the file was renamed.
2. Do an `hg rename` to the new filename, and ensure the contents of the file are the same as on the main branch.
3. `hg commit`.
4. `hg update` to the main branch.
5. `hg merge --tool internal:other` the new branch into the main branch.

From the merged commit onwards Mercurial should know about the rename.

Comment: No way for a flat history without a merge?

Comment: You could try rebasing the new changeset on top of the main branch.